# React Native's fetch method fails for HTTP request in release build

Tags: react-native

In react native app, the HTTP request fails with an empty exception in release build both in emulator and device. But the same request works fine in development build. However, HTTPS request works. I require both the protocols should work with this app.

android:usesCleartextTraffic is set to true

*npx react-native build-android --mode=release*

Comment: why this is negated?

Comment: This is a legitimate question. I had a similar issue. The fix is in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create network_security_config.xml file in android/app/src/main/res/xml folder and add the following code in the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config> 
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com or IP Address</domain> 
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Step 2: Add the networkSecurityConfig line in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<application
     ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml

**android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**
as in:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
....
```